# JAAS DatabaseServerLoginModule rolesQuery does not return user roles

Tags: jboss7.x, jaas, database-server

I'm using JAAS with JBoss as 7. The login module used is `DatabaseServerLoginModule`. Here is my configuration:

```
<login-module code="Database" flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/oracleDS"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWD FROM FO.USERS WHERE USERNAME=?"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT USERROLES, 'ROLES' FROM FO.USERROLES WHERE USERNAME=?"/>
</login-module>
```

The authentication occurred successfully without any problems (the login module is able to recuperate the password of the given username). But my problem is that it can not recuperate the roles using the `rolesQuery` and thus the authorization fails. For example for a user `krisv` with role `dme`, if I execute the `rolesQuery` inside a `scrapbook` in eclipse i got this result:
[image]
However when I want to access a web page that has role `dme` as `auth-constraint` i get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ROLES' parts is read by JBOSS and it only understands camelcase  it should read 'Roles' tell me how that works out for you

```
"SELECT USERROLES, 'Roles' FROM FO.USERROLES WHERE USERNAME=?"
```